# How to print list of packages for which a given package is required in Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, dependencies

I am searching for the command-line equivalent of [`apt-cache rdepends <package>`](https://askubuntu.com/a/128527) in Debian, i.e. locate all packages for which the given `<package>` is required.

[`cygcheck.exe`](https://drupal.star.bnl.gov/STAR/blog/jeromel/2012/feb/19/how-find-which-cygwin-package-contains-a-particular-file) doesn't seem to have such mode.

Running `setup.exe` and try to uninstall e.g. `libserf1` to get the list of packages to be also uninstalled is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

For dependency info you need the `cygcheck-dep` package.

Checking all packages that directly need a package.

```
$ cygcheck-dep -n libglpk40

 libglpk40: is needed for ( glpk lib4ti2_0 libglpk-devel octave )
```

Checking all packages directly required by a package.

```
$ cygcheck-dep -r libglpk40

 libglpk40: requires ( cygwin libgcc1 )
```